# Drupal / Jquery horizontal scrolling div

Tags: jquery, drupal, scroll

I'm trying to create something similar to this (http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html) in Drupal but I'm finding it difficult.

An example of where I am wanting to use it is http://hotness.bangtest.co.uk/work the part beheath the slider.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Your question is very vague, try being more concrete, what do you want, where are you at, what's the hindrance. Fx is the problem the JavaScript or the markup generated by Drupal? Adding the JS files etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Views carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewscarousel) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> In an effort to minimize the duplication of jcarousel based modules this module is being deprecated for the Drupal 6 version onward and is being replaced by the [jcarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module. As of the Drupal 6 2.x branch of the jcarousel module views integration is provided.
>
> The carousel module, jcarousel module, and this module are being merged into one effort with the maintainers combining efforts in one module.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you!